# arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: [] in django

Tags: django, url

I am new to django ..the same question is there already but i cant understand what this error is.. i keep getting this error in the url line. pls help me to resolve this error with explanation.

views.py

```
def srch(request):
   return render(request,'feeds/search.html')
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^search/$',views.srch,name='search')
```

and in html

```
<a href="{% url 'feeds:search' %}"> click </a>
```

thanks in advance for ur help ..

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can try replacing        {% url 'feeds:search' %} with         {% url 'search' %}"> ?

Answer (score 1):

you must read about URL namespace.. and also check in your project level **urls.py** entry of  `feeds` application which should be like

`url(r'feeds/',include('feeds.urls',namespace='feeds'))`..

I might not be correct but I think problem is in `urls.py` of your project

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I solved it by redirecting like this:

```
url(r'^password-reset/$', login_views.password_reset, {'post_reset_redirect' : 'password-reset/done/'}, name='password_reset')
```

So, I also have the:

```
url(r'^password-reset/done/$', login_views.password_reset_done, name='password_reset_done')
```